# HTML5 CSS Help - Enlarge Images on Hover, Borders around Images

Tags: html, css, web

What I need is really simple ---images of projects that can be scrolled thru; enlarge image 2% on hover; enlarge to full size on click (with background blurred); adjustable width borders and spaces around the images; columns for text to separate projects. I decided to go with the "Parallelism" and "Ethereal" HTML5 templates found here:

html5up.net/parallelism

html5up.net/ethereal

Parallelism has the ability to put spaces around the images and borders around the images, which is great. What I need though, is to be able to create some columns between projects and also where I can insert larger images. The Parallelism page is just divided into two rows (Top and Bottom), with no columns and the rows are too small in height. I need the images to be much bigger (less empty space above and below the horizontal rows and hopefully, soon, some columns too). The two rows of images only use about 1/3 of the screen height; I would like it to be more like 3/4.

The Ethereal site template has the columns (with colored background and text fields) and ability to post larger images that span both rows, but I cannot create spaces around the images, or use borders. It does not have enlarge thumbnail on mouse hover either. I cannot get the features of one site into the other, either way I try. When I tried to recreate the effects from one site in the other, it broke the website.

THANK YOU!
VK

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Ethereal by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @ajlkn
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ethereal by HTML5 UP</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
    </head>
    <body class="is-preload">

        <!-- Page Wrapper -->
            <div id="page-wrapper">

                <!-- Wrapper -->
                    <div id="wrapper">

                        <!-- Panel (Banner) -->
                            <section class="panel banner right">
                                <div class="content color0 span-3-75">
                                    <h1 class="major">Hello, my name<br />
                                    is Ethereal</h1>
                                    <p>This is <strong>Ethereal</strong>, a free site template by AJ for <a href="https://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>. It’s fully responsive, built on HTML5 and CSS3, and released entirely for free under the Creative Commons license. Hope you dig it :)</p>
                                    <ul class="actions">
                                        <li><a href="#first" class="button primary color1 circle icon solid fa-angle-right">Next</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="image filtered span-1-75" data-position="25% 25%">
                                    <img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </section>

                        <!-- Panel (Spotlight) -->
                            <section class="panel spotlight medium right" id="first">
                                <div class="content span-7">
                                    <h2 class="major">Sed etiam aenean</h2>
                                    <p>Mauris et ligula arcu. Proin dapibus convallis accumsan. Lorem maximus hendrerit orci, sit amet elementum massa hendrerit sed. Donec et ullamcorper ligula. Suspendisse amet potenti. Ut pretium libero eleifend euismod sed tristique. Quisque dictum magna risus, id ultricies justo sagittis vitae. Sed id odio tempor, porttitor elit amet, gravida hendrerit fringilla lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="image filtered tinted" data-position="top left">
                                    <img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </section>

                        <!-- Panel -->
                            <section class="panel color1">
                                <div class="intro joined">
                                    <h2 class="major">Amet lorem</h2>
                                    <p>Sed vel nibh libero. Mauris et lorem pharetra massa lorem turpis congue pulvinar. Vivamus sed feugiat finibus. Duis amet bibendum amet sed. Duis mauris ex, dapibus sed ligula tempus volutpat magna etiam.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <ul class="grid-icons three connected">
                                        <li><span class="icon fa-gem"><span class="label">Lorem</span></span></li>
                                        <li><span class="icon solid fa-camera-retro"><span class="label">Ipsum</span></span></li>
                                        <li><span class="icon solid fa-cog"><span class="label">Dolor</span></span></li>
                                        <li><span class="icon solid fa-paper-plane"><span class="label">Sit</span></span></li>
                                        <li><span class="icon solid fa-chart-bar"><span class="label">Amet</span></span></li>
                                        <li><span class="icon solid fa-code"><span class="label">Nullam</span></span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </section>

                        <!-- Panel (Spotlight) -->
                            <section class="panel spotlight large left">
                                <div class="content span-5">
                                    <h2 class="major">Magna amet tempus</h2>
                                    <p>Mauris a cursus velit. Nunc lacinia sollicitudin egestas bibendum, magna dui bibendum ex, sagittis commodo enim risus sed magna nulla. Vestibulum ut consequat velit. Curabitur vitae libero lorem. Quisque iaculis porttitor blandit. Nullam quis sagittis maximus. Sed vel nibh libero. Mauris et lorem pharetra massa lorem turpis congue pulvinar.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="image filtered tinted" data-position="top right">
                                    <img src="images/pic03.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </section>

                        <!-- Panel -->
                            <section class="panel">
                                <div class="intro color2">
                                    <h2 class="major">Elit integer</h2>
                                    <p>Sed vel nibh libero. Mauris et lorem pharetra massa lorem turpis congue pulvinar. Vivamus sed feugiat finibus. Duis amet bibendum amet sed. Duis mauris ex, dapibus sed ligula tempus volutpat magna etiam.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="gallery">
                                    <div class="group span-3">
                                        <a href="images/gallery/fulls/01.jpg" class="image filtered span-3" data-position="bottom"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                        <a href="images/gallery/fulls/02.jpg" class="image filtered span-1-5" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                        <a href="images/gallery/fulls/03.jpg" class="image filtered span-1-5" data-position="bottom"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/03.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="images/gallery/fulls/04.jpg" class="image filtered span-2-5" data-position="top"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/04.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    <div class="group span-4-5">
                                        <a href="images/gallery/fulls/05.jpg" class="image filtered span-3" data-position="top"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/05.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                        <a href="images/gallery/fulls/06.jpg" class="image filtered span-1-5" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/06.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                        <a href="images/gallery/fulls/07.jpg" class="image filtered span-1-5" data-position="bottom"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/07.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                        <a href="images/gallery/fulls/08.jpg" class="image filtered span-3" data-position="top"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/08.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="images/gallery/fulls/09.jpg" class="image filtered span-2-5" data-position="right"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/09.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                </div>
                            </section>

                        <!-- Panel -->
                            <section class="panel color4-alt">
                                <div class="intro color4">
                                    <h2 class="major">Contact</h2>
                                    <p>Sed vel nibh libero. Mauris et lorem pharetra massa lorem turpis congue pulvinar. Vivamus sed feugiat finibus. Duis amet bibendum amet sed. Duis mauris ex, dapibus sed ligula tempus volutpat magna etiam.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inner columns divided">
                                    <div class="span-3-25">
                                        <form method="post" action="#">
                                            <div class="fields">
                                                <div class="field half">
                                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="field half">
                                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="field">
                                                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                                                    <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4"></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <ul class="actions">
                                                <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="button primary" /></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span-1-5">
                                        <ul class="contact-icons color1">
                                            <li class="icon brands fa-twitter"><a href="#">@untitled-tld</a></li>
                                            <li class="icon brands fa-facebook-f"><a href="#">facebook.com/untitled</a></li>
                                            <li class="icon brands fa-snapchat-ghost"><a href="#">@untitled-tld</a></li>
                                            <li class="icon brands fa-instagram"><a href="#">@untitled-tld</a></li>
                                            <li class="icon brands fa-medium-m"><a href="#">medium.com/untitled</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </section>

                        <!-- Panel -->
                            <section class="panel color2-alt">
                                <div class="intro color2">
                                    <h2 class="major">Elements</h2>
                                    <p>Sed vel nibh libero. Mauris et lorem pharetra massa lorem turpis congue pulvinar. Vivamus sed feugiat finibus. Duis amet bibendum amet sed. Duis mauris ex, dapibus sed ligula tempus volutpat magna etiam. </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inner columns aligned">
                                    <div class="span-2-75">

                                        <h3 class="major">Text</h3>
                                        <p>This is <b>bold</b> and this is <strong>strong</strong>. This is <i>italic</i> and this is <em>emphasized</em>.
                                        This is <sup>superscript</sup> text and this is <sub>subscript</sub> text.
                                        This is <u>underlined</u> and this is code: <code>for (;;) { ... }</code>. Finally, <a href="#">this is a link</a>.</p>

                                        <h1>Heading Level 1</h1>
                                        <h2>Heading Level 2</h2>
                                        <h3>Heading Level 3</h3>
                                        <h4>Heading Level 4</h4>
                                        <h5>Heading Level 5</h5>
                                        <h6>Heading Level 6</h6>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span-3">

                                        <h4>Blockquote</h4>
                                        <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Felis sagittis eget tempus euismod. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in vestibulum. Blandit adipiscing eu iaculis volutpat ac adipiscing volutpat ac adipiscing faucibus.</blockquote>

                                        <h4>Preformatted</h4>
                                        <pre><code>i = 0;

while (!deck.isInOrder()) {
    print 'Iteration ' + (i++);
    deck.shuffle();
}

print 'It took ' + i + ' iterations to sort the deck.';</code></pre>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span-1-25">

                                        <h3 class="major">Lists</h3>

                                        <h4>Unordered</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
                                            <li>Dolor pulvinar etiam.</li>
                                            <li>Etiam vel felis viverra.</li>
                                        </ul>

                                        <h4>Alternate</h4>
                                        <ul class="alt">
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
                                            <li>Dolor pulvinar etiam.</li>
                                            <li>Etiam vel felis viverra.</li>
                                            <li>Felis enim feugiat.</li>
                                        </ul>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span-1-5">

                                        <h4>Ordered</h4>
                                        <ol>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
                                            <li>Dolor pulvinar etiam.</li>
                                            <li>Etiam vel felis viverra.</li>
                                            <li>Felis enim feugiat.</li>
                                            <li>Etiam vel felis lorem.</li>
                                        </ol>

                                        <h4>Actions</h4>
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><a href="#" class="button primary color2">Default</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="button">Default</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="actions stacked">
                                            <li><a href="#" class="button primary color2">Default</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="button">Default</a></li>
                                        </ul>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span-1-25">

                                        <h4>Icons</h4>
                                        <ul class="icons">
                                            <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-facebook-f"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-github"><span class="label">GitHub</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-medium-m"><span class="label">Medium</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>

                                        <h4>Contact Icons</h4>
                                        <ul class="contact-icons color2">
                                            <li class="icon brands fa-twitter"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                                            <li class="icon brands fa-facebook-f"><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                                            <li class="icon brands fa-instagram"><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                                            <li class="icon brands fa-github"><a href="#">GitHub</a></li>
                                            <li class="icon brands fa-medium-m"><a href="#">Medium</a></li>
                                        </ul>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span-3">
                                        <h3 class="major">Table</h3>
                                        <h4>Default</h4>
                                        <div class="table-wrapper">
                                            <table>
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Name</th>
                                                        <th>Description</th>
                                                        <th>Price</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Item One</td>
                                                        <td>Ante turpis integer aliquet porttitor.</td>
                                                        <td>29.99</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Item Two</td>
                                                        <td>Vis ac commodo adipiscing arcu aliquet.</td>
                                                        <td>19.99</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Item Three</td>
                                                        <td> Morbi faucibus arcu accumsan lorem.</td>
                                                        <td>29.99</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Item Four</td>
                                                        <td>Vitae integer tempus condimentum.</td>
                                                        <td>19.99</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                                <tfoot>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2"></td>
                                                        <td>100.00</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tfoot>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span-3">
                                        <h4>Alternate</h4>
                                        <div class="table-wrapper">
                                            <table class="alt">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Name</th>
                                                        <th>Description</th>
                                                        <th>Price</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Item One</td>
                                                        <td>Ante turpis integer aliquet porttitor.</td>
                                                        <td>29.99</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Item Two</td>
                                                        <td>Vis ac commodo adipiscing arcu aliquet.</td>
                                                        <td>19.99</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Item Three</td>
                                                        <td> Morbi faucibus arcu accumsan lorem.</td>
                                                        <td>29.99</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Item Four</td>
                                                        <td>Vitae integer tempus condimentum.</td>
                                                        <td>19.99</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Item Five</td>
                                                        <td>Ante turpis integer aliquet porttitor.</td>
                                                        <td>29.99</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                                <tfoot>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2"></td>
                                                        <td>100.00</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tfoot>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span-2-25">
                                        <h3 class="major">Buttons</h3>
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><a href="#" class="button primary color2">Primary</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="button">Default</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><a href="#" class="button">Default</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="button large">Large</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="button small">Small</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><a href="#" class="button primary color2 icon solid fa-cog">Icon</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="button icon fa-gem">Icon</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><span class="button primary color2 disabled">Disabled</span></li>
                                            <li><span class="button disabled">Disabled</span></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><a href="#" class="button primary color2 circle icon solid fa-cog">Icon</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="button circle icon fa-gem">Icon</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span-4-5">
                                        <h3 class="major">Form</h3>
                                        <form method="post" action="#">
                                            <div class="fields">
                                                <div class="field third">
                                                    <label for="demo-name">Name</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="demo-name" id="demo-name" value="" placeholder="Jane Doe" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="field third">
                                                    <label for="demo-email">Email</label>
                                                    <input type="email" name="demo-email" id="demo-email" value="" placeholder="jane@untitled.tld" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="field third">
                                                    <label for="demo-category">Category</label>
                                                    <div class="select-wrapper">
                                                        <select name="demo-category" id="demo-category">
                                                            <option value="">-</option>
                                                            <option value="1">Manufacturing</option>
                                                            <option value="1">Shipping</option>
                                                            <option value="1">Administration</option>
                                                            <option value="1">Human Resources</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="field quarter">
                                                    <input type="radio" id="demo-priority-low" name="demo-priority" class="color2" checked />
                                                    <label for="demo-priority-low">Low Priority</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="field quarter">
                                                    <input type="radio" id="demo-priority-high" name="demo-priority" class="color2" />
                                                    <label for="demo-priority-high">High Priority</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="field quarter">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" id="demo-copy" name="demo-copy" class="color2" />
                                                    <label for="demo-copy">Email a copy</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="field quarter">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" id="demo-human" name="demo-human" class="color2" checked />
                                                    <label for="demo-human">Not a robot</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="field">
                                                    <label for="demo-message">Message</label>
                                                    <textarea name="demo-message" id="demo-message" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="2"></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <ul class="actions">
                                                <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="primary color2" /></li>
                                                <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </section>

                        <!-- Copyright -->
                            <div class="copyright">&copy; Untitled. Design: <a href="https://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>.</div>

                    </div>

            </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I tried to recreate the effects from one site in the other, it broke the website.

Comment: From your description it sounds as though it would be simpler to ditch trying to use other people's templates and instead code the CSS from scratch yourself. Can you provide a picture of what you want the basic layout to look like - a handrawn sketch will do.